# Equality of optimization problems of the soft-margin SVM (moving constraint to objective function)

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm

I'm reading the derivation of the soft-margin SVM optimization problem in Elements of Statistical learning. In it, the authors claim that
\begin{align}
    \min_{} \quad & \| \mathbf{w}\| \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & y_i(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x_i}+b) \geq (1-\epsilon_i) \\
    \quad & \epsilon_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i \\
    \quad & \sum_{i=1}^m\epsilon_i \leq C\\
     \
\end{align}

(which is equation 12.7 in the book) is equal to this
\begin{align}
    \min_{b, \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{\epsilon}} \quad & \frac{1}{2}\| \mathbf{w}\|^2 + C\sum_{i=1}^m\epsilon_i \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad & y_i(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x_i}+b) \geq 1-\epsilon_i \\
    \quad & \epsilon_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i
\end{align}

(which is equation 12.8 in the book).

My question is how can you move the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^m\epsilon_i \leq C$ to the objective function in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your suspicion: you cannot. But, I believe the confusion stems from your misquoting the authors. In (12.7) they don't use , but `constant`. Using your variables (in the original, the authors use $\beta$'s and $\xi$'s instead of $w$, $b$ and the $\epsilon$'s, but that's not the issue), the condition is:

$$
\sum \epsilon_i \leq \text{constant}
$$

and below (12.8) the authors state:

> where the "cost" parameter $C$ replaces the constant in (12.7); the separable case corresponds to $C = \infty$.

So $C$ and `constant` are not the same. It is easy to see that, in a linearly non-separable case, if you choose a small enough `constant` the problem becomes unsolvable. As the `constant` $ \rightarrow 0$, all $\epsilon_i$ must approach zero, too. For sufficiently small $\epsilon_i$'s, the condition

$$
y_i(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x_i}+b) \geq 1-\epsilon_i
$$

becomes unsatisfiable, unless the data set is separable. For $C$ it's the opposite: As $C  \rightarrow 0$, all falsely classified points are being ignored, and any separation boundary satisfies the conditions.

Interestingly, equivalent formulas in machine learning literature (e.g. the formula above (6.3) in Cristianini and Shawe-Taylor, "Support Vector Machines" or (7.19-20) in Bishop, "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning") don't have that constraint on $\epsilon_i$'s. In [their seminal paper](http://image.diku.dk/imagecanon/material/cortes_vapnik95.pdf), Cortes and Vapnik (the inventors of the SVMs) also don't use this notation.

The formula (12.8) is nevertheless correct, i.e. congruent with other literature ((6.3) in Cristianini and Shawe-Taylor, (7.21) in Bishop, (24) in Cortes and Vapnik).